# SQL - INSERT IF NOT EXIST, CHECK if the same OR UPDATE

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want the DBMS to help me gain speed when doing a lot of inserts.

Today I do an INSERT Query in Java and catch the exception if the data already is in the database. 
The exception I get is :

```
SQLite Exception : [19] DB[1] exec() columns recorddate, recordtime are not unique.
```

If I get an exception I do a `SELECT Query` with the primary keys (`recorddate, recordtime`) and compare the result with the data I am trying to insert in Java. If it is the same I continue with next insert, otherwise I evaluate the data and decide what to save and maybe do an UPDATE.

This process takes time and I would like to speed it up.

I have thought of `INSERT IF NOT EXIST` but this just ignore the insert if there is any data with the same primary keys, am I right? And I want to make sure it is exactly the same data before I ignore the insert.

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to make this faster.

I'm using Java to handle large amount of data to insert into a SQLite database (SQLite v. 3.7.10). As the connection between Java and SQLite I am using sqlite4java (http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/)

Comment: ...Note that your current DB may run into issues - not all times are valid on all dates; you should be storing a single timestamp, not separated columns.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think letting the dbms handling more of that logic would be faster, at least not with plain SQL, as far as I can think of there is no "create or update" there.

When handling lots of entries often latency is an important issue, especially with dbs accessed via network, so at least in that case you want want to use mass operations whereever possible. Even if provided, "create or update" instead of select and update or insert (if even) would only half the latency.

I realize that is not what you asked for, but I would try to optimize in a different way, processing chunks of data, select all of them into a map then partition the input in creates, updates and ignores. That way ignores are almost for free, and further lookups are guaranteed to be done in memory. Unlikely that the dbms can be significantly faster.

If unsure if that is the right approach for you, profiling of overhead times should help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap *all* of your inserts and updates into a transaction. In SQL this will be written as follows.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Table(Col1,Col2) VALUES(Val1,Val2); 
COMMIT;
```

There are two things to note here: the database paging and commits will not be written to disk until `COMMIT` is called, speeding up your queries *significantly*; the second thing is the `INSERT OR REPLACE` syntax, which does precisely what you want for `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` fields.

Most database wrappers have a special syntax for managing transactions. You can certainly execute a query, `BEGIN`, followed by your inserts and updates, and finish by executing `COMMIT`. Read the database wrapper documentation.

One more thing you can do is switch to [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). Run the following command, only once, on the database.

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = wal;
```

Comment: -1 Is pointless creating a transaction over a single statement!

Comment: @LS_dev, you're correct, which is why I said "all of your inserts and updates". I was providing an example in the snippet you're referencing. Recall this question was about performance, and my point is one should perform database writes in a transaction, this is especially true for SQLite.

Comment: I am already using transactions and it is helping a lot, but still to slow.
I will try your PRAGMA-command. But your SQL-QUERY does not do what I want, it updates the database with the new values without comparing them, I want to know if they are the same, otherwise I have to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I would:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table SET othervalues=... WHERE recorddate=... AND recordtime=...;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table(recorddate, recordtime, ...) VALUES(...);
COMMIT;
```

`UPDATE` will update all existing rows, ignoring non existent because of `WHERE` clause.

`INSERT` will then add new rows, ignoring existing because of `IGNORE`.

Comment: This is not doing the work I want. For every insert you have two queries and never compare with the data stored in the database. The ultimate query for me would be an INSERT-query that returns data if there is any with the primary keys of the insert.

Comment: What do you mean compare? Unique data must be properly specified with `CREATE TABLE ... (... UNIQUE, ...)`. That way, "comparison" is done automatically according schema.

Comment: I mean that the database table holds data from previous inserts and if a new insert has the same primary key as an old that is already stored in the table I want to compare the new and the old (already stored in table) data to make a decision which data to keep.

Comment: This way you must specify your decision requirements.

Comment: I can't do that without make a select-Query first to know whats in the database... And there you have my problem this process I'm doing takes to long.